# How can I make the blank-screen key work on my Logitech R400 in Linux?

Tags: linux, keymapping, logitech

**updated, problem solved**

I use a Logitech R400 remote to control my presentations on Linux. All my presentation are PDF's, displayed using Acroread (it provides the best graphics). Forward/backward works out of the box, but sometimes I would like to blank the screen. Running "sleep 1; xset s activate" would do the trick. How do I make the R400 do this?

In my original post I was unable to get the desired result. With XFCE I could make it work.
This posting is now my working system. Could this be done more elegant / XFCE independent?

Right now I made /etc/udev/rules.d/026_logitech.rules containing:

```
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", IMPORT{builtin}="usb_id" 
    ENV{ID_VENDOR}=="Logitech*", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c538", RUN+="keymap $name /etc/udev/logitech-r400"
```

/etc/udev/logitech-r400 containing:

```
    0x70037 f10
    0x70029 f11
    0x7003E f11
    0x7004B PageUp
    0x7004E PageDown
```

~/bin/blank.sh containing

```
    #!/bin/bash
    sleep 1; xset s activate
```

And I used the XFCE keyboard-utility (Settings) to map F10 to ~/bin/blank.sh

I use Debian, so things might be Debian-specific.

Success

Comment: It would be great if you could reformulate this as a question (f.ex.: "How can I make the blank-screen key work on my Logitech R400 in Linux?). And then post your answer as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I see neither the question, nor the answer.